# NameError when running pyOpenGL

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-8.1, nameerror, pyopengl

I am interested in setting up an environment to code a particle simulator with pyOpenGL. I have installed pyOpenGL. 
This is the test code just to make sure that opengl works all right.

```
from OpenGL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *


window = 0 
width, height = 500,400

def draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)           
    glLoadIdentity()

glutDwapBuffers()                                           




#initialization
glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH)
glutInitWindowSize(width,height)
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0)
window = glutCreateWindow(b"noobtute")
glutDisplayFunc(draw)                                                                       
glutIdleFunc(draw)  
glutMainLoop()
```

However, when I run the script from command I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'glClear' is not defined
GLUT Display callback <function draw at 0x0000000002F8CB70> with (),{} failed: 
returning None name 'glClear' is not defined
```

I have tried reinstalling pyOpengl but have had no success.

I am running Python 3.4 on Windows 8.1

If you think more information would be helpful just ask.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
from OpenGL import *
```

to

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
```

However, I favor using this format:

```
import OpenGL.GL as GL
import OpenGL.GLU as GLU
import OpenGL.GLUT as GLUT


window = 0 
width, height = 500,400

def draw():
    GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)           
    GL.glLoadIdentity()
    GLUT.glutSwapBuffers()                                           




#initialization
GLUT.glutInit()
GLUT.glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT.GLUT_RGBA | GLUT.GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT.GLUT_ALPHA |
GLUT.GLUT_DEPTH)
GLUT.glutInitWindowSize(width,height)
GLUT.glutInitWindowPosition(0,0)
window = GLUT.glutCreateWindow(b"noobtute")
GLUT.glutDisplayFunc(draw)                                                                       
GLUT.glutIdleFunc(draw)  
GLUT.glutMainLoop()
```

While not as compact, it helps me keep straight who's doing what.

Comment: So your solution worked just fine, thanks a bunch. I understand why it is easier to understand and cleaner code, but i am still confused as to why the code that I origionally posted was not working.